# Why use vector sum for calculating neutral current?

Tags: three-phase, phasor, neutral

In a three phase system, we use a vector sum to calculate resulting neutral current.

I don't understand why we use vector sum. The resulting neutral current is actually the sum of instantaneous values of 3 phase currents right? So even if we use a phasor diagram to represent the currents, it should not be a vector sum; it should just be the sum of the y axis components (sin components) of the currents.

Also, when we are given 3 phase current values to calculate the resultant neutral, are we given RMS or instantaneous values, or the maxima? It cannot be instantaneous because otherwise neutral would be a simple addition of them.

I am not a physics student; I am just trying to understand this for a use-case project, so it would be helpful if someone helps me reconcile all these facts. Thanks!

Comment: The sum of any number of sinusoids at the same frequency is a single sinusoid at that frequency. They add vectorially because they probably have different phase angles.

Answer (score 1):

If you just sum the instantaneous currents of three phases, and they do not sum to zero due to imbalance, you get the instantaneous current running in the neutral wire.

But that is also a sine wave, with some amplitude and some phase. So it is a vector sum. So having a single point in time might add up that neutral current is 0 at some instant,  but in reality it is a sine wave which just happened to be at the zero crossing at that instant and it does not mean the current is 0 since it has amplitude and phase.

Comment: Yes exactly, then why do we say neutral current is zero in balanced system? Am i wrong in assuming neutral current is also a sine wave, which is instantaneous sum of phase currents?

Comment: All currents must sum to zero at all times. If there is imbalance in the load, like someone using 0A on two phases and 1A on one phase, then there is no other return path for the 1A except for the neutral wire. Yes, neutral current is also a sine wave and instantaneous sum of phase currents. The point is with balanced load the phase currents sum to zero so there is no imbalanced currents that would flow via neutral.